# Is it possible to deny a connection from changing ANSI_PADDING to OFF?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Our application occasionally throws errors if we ever apply filtered indexes because some of the C# application connections change the ANSI_PADDING to OFF for some routines.
Is it possible to deny setting change on the session without raising an error, or use a database trigger to catch and reverse it?

Comment: Can you prevent the connection from the App side? The queries from the app clearly have this manually set. I might raise the case with the app devs

Comment: There are too many apps and too much code to update and deploy. Ideally, I need SQL Server to catch and deal with this, if possible.